# How does gitignore work?

Tags: git

Hello I'm new to git and I can't fully understand the .gitignore.

So let's say I have a Master Folder currently in Production and inside it there's a reports folder that I don't really need to track.

```
Master Folder
 |
 +-- file 1
 |    
 +-- dir 2
 |  |  
 |  \-- file 2.1
 |    
 +-- dir 3
 |  |  
 |  +-- file 3.1
 |  \-- file 3.2
 |    
 +-- Reports
 |  |  
 |  +-- file 4.1
 |  \-- file 4.2
```

Now, I wanted to modify the folder so I clone the Master Folder in my repository. Does the reports folder gets cloned too?

While I'm editing, some person added or changed files inside the reports folder.

After I finish editing, I need to update the Master Folder to what I've updated. If I git push my changes, will it affect the Reports Folder in the Master Folder?

Comment: You also seem to misunderstand how Git works in general: Changes are not automatically added to your repository. Only those changes that you add and then *commit* make it into the repository and will be cloned later. Consider reading [the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/).

Answer (score 8):

Before you commit the reports to master, make sure you create a new `.gitignore` file in the root of your project. Once this is done, include the paths of the folders or files to the gitignore file. Make sure you specify one path per line.

In your case, if you want to ignore all the files in your Reports folder, then add the following to the `.gitignore` file.

```
/Reports
```

If you want to exclude specific files, you can do something like

```
/Reports/*.docx
```

Assuming thst the reports are mixed file extensions but you want to ignore all word file reports from the folder.

About cloning, if someone tries to clone the project, he won't get any report files as they were not committed at first place. Also, making any changes in the Reports folder won't be tracked by git any more.

Comment: so does /Reports refer to the Reports directory in the root folder of the project? I don't have to write ./Reports ie I don't need the "." ?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne yes

Answer (score 1):

You must have to create a file inside your master folder named .gitignore and write the below line in your .gitignore file :

```
Reports/
```

now if you push your master folder then git will not track your Reports folder.

Comment: Better write `/Reports`

Comment: @Mr.Alien so what does adding Reports/ do differently, does it include *any* matching folder called Reports?

Comment: @SimonBosley yes

Answer (score 1):

Create a new .gitignore file in the root diectory of your folder and add file extensions or dir path which you want to exclude from. 
For ex :

```
.idea
.DS_Store
*.iml
src/main/resources/config.config
src/main/resources/conf/local
/target
screenshots/
/Reports
```

Like wise you can add file name or extensions which you want to exclude. 
Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern. When deciding whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome):

Patterns read from the command line for those commands that support them.

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the
>   path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level
>   files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those
>   in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These
>   patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file. A
>   project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository,
>   containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

Patterns read from $GIT_DIR/info/exclude.

Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable core.excludesFile.